# `df` within VPS shows available space far below provisioned space

Tags: vps, nix

I'm stuck on figuring out whether this is (1) a NixOS problem, (2) a Vultr problem, (3) something particular to my image.

I have a Vultr VPS running custom Nix image (18.09 Jellyfish), and the console shows an allocated space of **80G**.

Meanwhile, `df -h` shows me this:

```
[agam@nixos:~]$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        198M     0  198M   0% /dev
tmpfs           2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           989M  3.0M  986M   1% /run
tmpfs           2.0G  456K  2.0G   1% /run/wrappers
tmpfs           2.0G  401M  1.6G  21% /
/dev/root       1.1G  1.1G     0 100% /iso
/dev/loop0      1.1G  1.1G     0 100% /nix/.ro-store
tmpfs           2.0G  2.0G     0 100% /nix/.rw-store
unionfs         3.0G  3.0G     0 100% /nix/store
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           396M     0  396M   0% /run/user/0
tmpfs           396M     0  396M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Where is the rest of the allocated space?

`mount` shows:

```
[agam@nixos:~]$ mount
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=202364k,nr_inodes=504154,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=3,mode=620,ptmxmode=666)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,size=2023628k)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,size=1011816k,mode=755)
ramfs on /run/keys type ramfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,mode=750)
tmpfs on /run/wrappers type tmpfs (rw,nodev,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on / type tmpfs (rw,relatime,mode=755)
/dev/sr0 on /iso type iso9660 (ro,relatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048)
/iso/nix-store.squashfs on /nix/.ro-store type squashfs (ro,relatime)
tmpfs on /nix/.rw-store type tmpfs (rw,relatime,mode=755)
unionfs on /nix/store type fuse.unionfs (rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other)
unionfs on /nix/store type fuse.unionfs (ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup/unified type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd)
bpf on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/0 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=404724k,mode=700)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=404724k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=100)
```

I think I just have to manually install partition on the VPS-provided storage and somehow move `/` on to it:

`fdisk` shows:

```
Disk /dev/vda: 80 GiB, 85899345920 bytes, 167772160 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Comment: Root on tmpfs... not meant to last long? Likely needs a proper install.

Comment: `tmpfs           2.0G  401M  1.6G  21% /` and `/dev/root       1.1G  1.1G     0 100% /iso` make me think you've booted into a rescue image and not an installed OS.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the commenters, turns out I *was* being stupid after all, I had forgotten to actually *install* NixOS from the attached ISO (!)

After `fdisk /dev/vda`, creating a partition there, setting up `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` the right way and then `sudo nixos-install`, everything is as it should be.